# Provide dependencies for objects created by a factory method

Tags: go

Given the following interface:

```
type Store interface {
 // some methods
}
```

I am planning to create a "factory" which shall give me the correct `Store` implementation based on a value passed in:

```
func CreateStore(envVar EnvironmentProvider) Store {
   if envVar == "A" {
     return &StoreA{
              //dependencies to create a StoreA
             }
   else {
     return &DefaultStore { 
              // dependencies to create a DefaultStore 
             }
}
```

I am a little bit struggling with how to provide the dependencies for `StoreA` OR `DefaultStore`. They are depending on completely different objects and I don't want to pass in both, dependencies for `StoreA` and for `DefaultStore` as parameters to the `CreateStore` function. Further, there could be more implementation of `Store` in the future. Of course, I could simply create the dependencies in each if branch but this would not be nice to test. Which pattern do you use for such a situation in `go`?

Comment: Most likely your two different types should have their own constructors which return their own types respectively.  There is no benefit to returning a `Store` interface value over a `*StoreA` value, given type `*StoreA` implements `Store`.

Comment: Indeed, this is an anti-pattern. https://medium.com/@cep21/preemptive-interface-anti-pattern-in-go-54c18ac0668a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a registry pattern:

```
var storeRegistry=map[string]func() Store{}

func Register(name string,factory func() Store) {
   storeRegistry[name]=factory
}

func CreateStore(env EnvironmentProvider) Store {
   storeType:= // Determine store type from env
   return storeRegistry[env.StoreType]()
}
```

Then, each implementation can stay in its own package, and register their factory using `init()`:

```
package storeA

func init() {
   registrypkg.Register("storetype", func() registrypkg.Store {
        // create and return a new Store
    })
}
```